# Making changes to an ActionBar that is set via the theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.android, android-theme

I am trying to make some changes to the action bar so that when you click on the ActionBar icon, you will get brought back to the home screen. So i tried this approach:

```
ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == Android.Resource.Id.Home) {
            Intent home = new Intent(this, typeof(WelcomeScreen));
            home.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
            StartActivity(home);
        }
```

But to my surprise the icon is not clickable. I have tried using

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and this works, but i do not want to the `<-` associated with that method.

I have taken over this project for someone else and they have set up the action bar so that is a part of the theme. I am unsure as to how I can interact with the action bar on individual screens...

( I really want to add this implementation (back to home screen on icon press) on all screens so if that's a possibility that would be great)

Comment: Can you just extend AppCompatActivity and add toolbar like you should?

Comment: @Eenvincible no I cannot

Comment: By the way, I am not sure where ImenuItem came from; is that still android?

Comment: @Eenvincible I'm using Xamarin.Android, should have tagged it as such sorry about that

Comment: Oh okay  that is the one; I have never used Xamarin myself though